# Unix File name and path

Tags: directory

1. How can I get the full file name of any directory?
2. Is it possible that file path should also not be having any root directory?

Comment: What is meant by full file name of a directory , can you give an example ?

Answer (score 4):

POSIXly, to get a symlink-free absolute path of a directory where a path (possibly relative to the current directory, possibly with symlinks) to that is stored in `$dir`, provided you have *search* permission to that directory, you can do

```
(
  case $dir in
    (/*) CDPATH= cd -P "$dir";;
    ("") CDPATH= cd -P "";;
    (*) CDPATH= cd -P "./$dir";;
  esac && pwd -P
)
```

Here copied verbatim from [this text to be included in the next revision of the POSIX specification](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1045#c3749).

As noted there, for the `""` case, you may want to output an error instead of relying on a currently unspecified behaviour of `cd` or write it:

```
(
  case "${dir:?directory cannot be empty}" in
    (/*) CDPATH= cd -P "$dir";;
    (*) CDPATH= cd -P "./$dir";;
  esac && pwd -P
)
```

Note that the prefixing of `$dir` with `./` when not absolute is not so much for `$dir` not to be taken as an option when it starts with `-` (for which `CDPATH= cd -P -- "${dir:?cannot be empty}"` would be enough), but for the special value `-` instead which `cd` interprets as meaning the `$OLDPWD`, the *previous working directory* (and `CDPATH= OLDPWD=- cd -P -- "${dir:?cannot be empty}"` cannot be used portably to work around it).

One case where a *directory* can not have an absolute path is when it's the current directory and it has been unlinked from its parent:

```
$ mkdir 1
$ cd 1
$ rmdir ../1
$ cd -P .
$ ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x 0 chazelas chazelas 0 Mar 27 06:53 ./
$ [ -d . ] && echo yes
yes
```

Still there, but:

```
$ pwd -P
.
$ realpath .
realpath: .: No such file or directory
$ readlink -ve .
readlink: .: No such file or directory
```

It has no path on the file system.

The *No such file or directory* error is a bit misleading there as the `.` directory does exist (though one can't do much with it) but at least on Linux, `getcwd()` returns with a `ENOENT` errno to signify that the current directory has been unlinked.

Comment: In the first part of your answer, what's the rationale for separating the three cases?

Comment: I think it's really just two cases: relative paths not beginning with `/` (the third one here) and everything else (the other two) - because if `$dir` is empty, then `cd -P "$dir"` and `cd -P ""` would be identical, and the cases can be collapsed: `([!/]*) cd -P "./$dir" ;;` and `(*) cd -P "$dir" ;;` - unless I missed something. The `./` is probably for safety to guard against directories beginning with `-`.

Comment: @n.caillou and muru, see edit.

Comment: @muru, yes, the additional line for `""` was to stress the fact that an empty `$dir` has to be treated differently from relative paths, but yes, you can factorize the first 2 with `(/* | "")` for instance. See edit

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths do not contain the root directory, as they are relative to the current directory.

Example:

```
development/project/src
```

This is a relative path to something called `src` two levels of directories below the current directory.  The path does not say whether `src` is the name of a directory, file, or of something else.

On Linux systems, you may use the `realpath` utility to get the full (absolute) path of a name:

```
$ realpath development/project/src
/home/myuser/work/development/project/src
```

An absolute path always start with the root directory. To be more precise, it starts with the current process' root directory, which may be changed with the command `chroot`.

On most Unix systems you can prefix a relative path that starts at the current directory with `$PWD` to get the absolute path:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$PWD/development/project/src"
/home/myuser/work/development/project/src
```

however, this is just a string concatenation and does not resolve the path in exactly the same way as `realpath` does. Provided that the given relative path is correct, it will give a functional absolute path.